# how to inject a dependency in a subclass with nestjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

My service provider has a subclass and this subclass has a dependency.

I am having a hard time trying to make this work.

here is the controller where I inject the service class:

```
@Controller('/chat')
export class ChatController {
    constructor(
        private sendMessageAuthorizationService: SendMessageAuthorizationService
    ) {
    }

    @Get('/authorization')
    isAuthorized() {
        return JSON.stringify("hello world");
    }
}
```

here is the service class:

```
@Injectable()
export class SendMessageAuthorizationService {
    private getUserChatRule: GetUserChatRule;

    constructor(
        userChatGatway: UserChatGateway
        ) {
        this.getUserChatRule = new GetUserChatRule(userChatGatway);
    }

    execute() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

here is the subclass that has a dependency:

```
export default class GetUserChatRule {
    constructor(
        private readonly userChatGateay: UserChatGateway
    ) {
    }

    apply() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

here is the class that is being inject into the subclass GetUserChatRule

```
@Injectable()
export default class UserChatAdapter implements UserChatGateway {
    getUserChat() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

finally here is the module:

```
@Module({
    imports: [],
    controllers: [ChatController],
    providers: [SendMessageAuthorizationService, UserChatAdapter]
})
export class ChatModule {}
```

for reference, this is the error I get:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SendMessageAuthorizationService (?). 
Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the ChatModule context.
```

Comment: Are you wanting to inject `UserChatAdapter` into the`SendMessageAuthorizationService` so it can be passed to `GetUserChatRule`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel correct but the `UserChatAdapter` is a subclass dependency (GetUserChatRule), not the service class (SendMessageAuthorizationService)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel `UserChatAdapter` was meant to be just a parameter of the `SendMessageAuthorizationService` constructor

Comment: If you change the type of `UserChatGateway` to be `UserChatAdapter` in the `SendMessageAuthorizationService` this will work how you want it to

Comment: @JayMcDoniel is there a way to use interfaces to type the parameter? my intention is to guarantee that the `SendMessageAuthorizationService` will depend only on the abstraction

Comment: Directly, no, but you can do `@Inject(InjectionToken) private readonly implementation: Interface`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample project to test the [example](https://github.com/RedRosh/stackoverflow-77592690) that you provided.

the problem you are facing is not related to subclass but in the way you are injecting the **UserChatGateway**.

you can either use a custom [provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#non-class-based-provider-tokens) or inject the class using the @Inject().

**FIRST APPROACH**

```js
export default class GetUserChatRule {
  constructor(private readonly userChatGateway: UserChatGateway) {}

  apply() {
    return 'hello world';
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class SendMessageAuthorizationService {
  getUserChatRule: GetUserChatRule;

  constructor(@Inject(UserChatAdapter) userChatGateway: UserChatGateway) {
    this.getUserChatRule = new GetUserChatRule(userChatGateway);
  }

  execute() {
    return 'hello world';
  }
}
```

**SECOND APPROACH**

if you want to use custom provider, you can use the following logic :

In your chat.module :

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [ChatController],
  providers: [
    SendMessageAuthorizationService,
    {
      provide: USER_CHAT_GATEWAY,
      useClass: UserChatAdapter,
    },
  ],
})
export class ChatModule {}
```

In your send-message.service :

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(USER_CHAT_GATEWAY)
    userChatGateway: UserChatGateway,
  ) {
    this.getUserChatRule = new GetUserChatRule(userChatGateway);
  }
```

the USER_CHAT_GATEWAY is a constant that you can define in a constants.ts file

if you want to test the code using the second approach, I created a branch [here](https://github.com/RedRosh/stackoverflow-77592690/tree/custom-provider).

Using the custom provider, you can update the adapter without changing the service.

Comment: would be nice if the domain layer didn't depend on the application layer, is there a way to only type using the interfaces?

Comment: yes, it's possible to make such seperation using custom provider. I updated my solution. Please check the second approach.